# How to handle an exception thrown by a library without changing the original configuration used to make an API call?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Python 3 requests library to make an API call to HDFS service hosted on an AWS server, but it eventually fails. The first URL that I use to in the call contains an IP address as the hostname. The error message is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NatPs.png). In the error message, the URL is not the same as my original URL.

While the first call is running, the library internally receives another URL for redirection. The screenshot from the debugger is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O64PZ.png). The library makes a call to this redirected URL which fails.

Based on the getaddrinfo error, it looked like the API call was failing because the hostname was not in the correct format. I tried to test whether changing the hostname from something like "ip-10..." to just an IP address in the redirected URL would return a successful response. I did this by adding a condition to the connection module in urllib3. The condition is commented in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEkT9.png)

I made a new request with the original URL again and it returned the correct response. But I am unable to come up with a solution to handle this exception and change the format of the other URL without modifying the connection module or changing the original URL used in our code to start the request. What is the correct way to handle this exception from my backend application?

Edit: Code use to make the API call is shared below

```
modURL = http://<PRIVATE_IP>/webhdfs/v1/<dummy_path>?user.name=root&op=CREATE&overwrite=true

def writeFileListToHdfs(dirname, fileList):
    response = requests.put(url = modURL, data=fileList)
```

Comment: Can you please share your code to help debug? Use this as guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's just a one line code for the API call so I am not sure whether it will be helpful at all. You will probably need an HDFS service similar to what I am using on a private server to duplicate the issue. Anyway, I will share the snippet I used. While checking the HDFS API doc, I did find this link that mentions that the original API call will be temporarily redirected https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE